# Rails devise help routing error No route matches "/sessions/user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

When I login on my page I automatic go to the route: http://localhost:3000/sessions/user

And I get this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/sessions/user"
```

I have created a controller named sessions_controller.rb in users folder here it is:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have been logged out."
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:encrypted_password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login or password."
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have been logged out."
  end
end
```

My route file:

```
Densidste::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user

 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" } do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "opret", :to => 'users/users#new'
    get "logud", :to => 'users/users#destroy'
  end
  resources :sessions
  resources :users

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }

  resources :aktivs
  resources :taggingposts
  resources :tags
  resources :kommentares
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: What are you expecting to define that route?

Comment: I am expecting that my session controller works and redirects to the root url with the notice "Succesfully loged in"

Answer (score 7):

(Old question but I ran into the same issue when setting up Devise, so hope this helps others)

Removing `resources :sessions` from the routes file should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For those who experiencing this issue with `Devise 2.0` and `Rails 3.2.1` and checked all the observations made by @Micah Alcorn but still facing the problem — *restart your web server*. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `root_url` defined. It is still pointing to the static public/index.html. (edited out by Ryan Bigg)

`devise_for :users` is stated twice.

`resources :users` is unnecessary unless you have a RESTful controller handling destroy and index actions outside of devise.

Do you, in fact, have a "users" controller for that first edit action too? That should probably be in a custom `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`.